# Can't remove textfield with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a list of different data entries.  Each row containing an entry displays multiple values with an edit button at the end of the row.  Right now I am just trying to build the functionality of editing each row.

What I want to have happen is when the user clicks on the edit button, several fields in the row that the button is located in become editable text fields.  When the user clicks the button again (whose name has now changed to 'save'), the text fields just turn into non-editable text again.

I have the first part of this working right.  However, when I try to get the text fields to turn into regular text, the text fields remain and the text within them disappears.  Here is my javascript code:

```
var App = 
    {
        editing_list: false,
        default_text: 'hello world!',
        edit_element: null,
        editing_html: 
            "<textarea name= \"expiration_date\">list expiration date</textarea>",
        normal_html: 
            "<td name= \"expiration_date\">list expiration date</td>",
    };

function on_edit_button_click()
{
    if(App.editing_list)
    {
        $("textarea[name=expiration_date]").html(App.normal_html);
        $(this).html("edit");

        App.editing_list = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("td[name=expiration_date]").html(App.editing_html);
        $(this).html("save");

        App.editing_list = true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    $('button').click(on_edit_button_click);
});

function init()
{
    App.edit_element = $("td[name=expiration_date]");
    console.log(App.edit_element);
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<table style="width:300px">
    <tr name="list_*id*_row">
        <td name="list_name">list name</td>
        <td name="expiration_date">list expiration date</td>
        <td><button> edit </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `style="width=300px"` is not a valid CSS syntax.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed that.  Edited it.  However, the original problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the "Save" button, your code is trying to change the "textarea" html `$("textarea[name=expiration_date]")`

Change that to the table cell `$("td[name=expiration_date]")` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates what you seemed to be asking about](http://jsfiddle.net/kenny_evitt/DP6m4/).

If you inspect the HTML elements when you run your original example code, you should observe that the code isn't in fact removing the `<td>` element when you first click the "edit" button; it's *inserting* the `<textarea>` element *inside it*.

One important difference in my example code is that I replaced your use of the [jQuery function `html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with [the jQuery function `replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) as the `html` function will (according to the documentation to which I just linked):

> Get the HTML **contents** of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML **contents** of every matched element." [emphasis mine]

I also added code to save the *existing* contents of the `textarea` and `td` elements before they're replaced so that the contents of the new element can be updated with the same value as the element that was replaced.

Here's the full JavaScript from the JSFiddle:

```
var App = 
    {
        editing_list: false,
        default_text: 'hello world!',
        edit_element: null,
        editing_html: 
            "<textarea name=\"expiration_date\">editing</textarea>",
        normal_html: 
            "<td name=\"expiration_date\">normal</td>",
    };

function on_edit_button_click()
{
    if(App.editing_list)
    {
        var $textArea = $("textarea[name=expiration_date]");
        var currentValue = $textArea.val();
        console.debug(currentValue);
        $textArea.replaceWith(App.normal_html);
        $("td[name=expiration_date]").html(currentValue);
        $(this).html("edit");
        App.editing_list = false;
    }
    else
    {
        var $td = $("td[name=expiration_date]");
        var currentValue = $td.html();
        console.debug(currentValue);
        $td.replaceWith(App.editing_html);
        $("textarea[name=expiration_date]").html(currentValue);
        $(this).html("save");
        App.editing_list = true;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('button').click(on_edit_button_click);
});
```

Note that I also removed the `init();` function call from your example as it isn't defined elsewhere in your code.

I also changed the contents of the `editing_html` and `normal_html` HTML but those contents are never visible (because they're replaced).